# CentOS 6 & Apache2.2 VHost Configurations

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, subdomain, httpd, virtualhost

I have a personal VPS configured to host two domains that I purchased, I managed to configure Apache correctly and get both domains able to point to their own directories and show correctly.

I want to add a sub-domain to one of my domains, but even with the same configurations I cannot get it to work. I have both domains, and sub-domain listed in /etc/hosts as with the server IP.

```
NameVirtualHost 203.143.84.37:80

<VirtualHost 203.143.84.37:80>
    ServerName mitiamosports.com.au
    ServerAlias www.mitiamosports.com.au
    DocumentRoot /home/sports/public_html
    UseCanonicalName Off
    <Directory />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost 203.143.84.37:80>
    ServerName portal.mitiamosports.com.au
    ServerAlias www.portal.mitiamosports.com.au
    DocumentRoot /home/sports/public_html/portal
    UseCanonicalName Off
    <Directory />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I do a NSLookup of the subdomain, it says it is fine but when trying to access it in the browser, the server cannot find the address.

I have two A records pointing to the IP address, both "portal" and "www.portal". I have tried to use the same configuration that cPanel uses, in hopes it would work, but no success.

Any help would be appreciated! Cannot seem to find a definitive answer.

Comment: Wait an hour and try again.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I've waited several hours.

Answer (score 1):

`portal.mitiamosports.com.au` works for me (although I get a directly listing, not a site) so I'm guessing you have a negative DNS cache somewhere.

```
$ host portal.mitiamosports.com.au
portal.mitiamosports.com.au has address 203.143.84.37
```

If you can flush your DNS caches (on your computer, and any upstream caches) then it should start working. Otherwise you will have to wait for the negative cache's to timeout before they  will try resolving it again rather than using the negative cache.

Comment: I'm glad it's working for you! I've tried flushing DNS, and clearing cache. Do you see an "admin" directory?

Comment: So it seems I can access the sub-domain in IE and Chrome, but not Firefox.. I am not sure why.

Comment: When I try access the sub domain in Chrome and go into the admin directory I am getting a error 500.. These are just PHP files which should be working.

Comment: Yes, I get a 500 error too. You'll need to look at your Apache logs to determine why. Probably file system permissions not allowing Apache user access to the directory.

Comment: Thanks, I will try look at the logs to see what is happening. All permissions are same for both domains etc, but I will enable logs again and check them out.

Comment: So after playing around, I can now safely say that http://portal.mitiamosports.com.au opens in ANY web browser but Firefox/Waterfox on my laptop. I have even tried with my phone and it works, why can't it open in my Firefox browser? I've cleared cache, flushed dns, rebooted, tried different proxies and no luck.

Comment: You mentioned you were playing with your /etc/hosts file; have you cleaned that out?